# HTML Fill up div with select and input

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/z5gt4tLe/2/

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="my_bar">
    <div id="my_input">
        <select name="my_name">
            <option value="5min">5-Min</option>
            <option value="1hour">Hour</option>
            <option value="1day">Day</option>
        </select>
    </div> <span>
        <input type="submit" id="my_input_submit" value="Submit">
    </span>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#my_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background: green;
}
#my_bar span {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0px
}
#my_input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
#my_input_submit {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

I want `select` to be maximized to fill up the height of the `div` and
also horizontally fill up all the extra space between the `select` menu and the submit button so that I do not see any green in the background.

Please help me figure this out.

`width: 100%` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5gt4tLe/9/)**

```
<div id="my_bar">

        <select name="my_name">
            <option value="5min">5-Min</option>
            <option value="1hour">Hour</option>
            <option value="1day">Day</option>
        </select>


        <input type="submit" id="my_input_submit" value="Submit">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#my_bar {
    height: 45px;
    background: green;
}
#my_bar select{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
}
#my_input_submit {
    height: 100%;
    width:10%;
    float: right;
}
```

if you don't like `%` you can always keep this solution for older browsers, and just include some more exact calculations using CSS3's `calc()`

Comment: This breaks on Chrome.  However, setting `float: left` on `#my_bar select` fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/ocfe6bxt/.

Comment: @DRD strange it works flawlessly for me on chrome as is

Comment: @aw04: In my Chrome (Version 36.0.1985.143) the Submit button is carried on a new line.

Comment: @drd ok added `float:left;` just to be sure

Comment: @DRD Interesting, must have changed since then. I'm on 37.*

Comment: This is shrinking and growing the submit button.  I probably wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but the basics are here...

http://jsfiddle.net/z5gt4tLe/5/

Set the body & html height and width to 100%.  Set the width to a calculation of 100% - width of button (`width: calc(100% - 60px);`) and now you need to tidy up the mess I created.

Oh, I also set border/margin/padding to 0 on all elements.  You will need to add them where you want them.  I always consider this wise for cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox to the rescue: http://jsfiddle.net/rj05v1yg/. (Requires a modern browser).

HTML:

```
<div id="my_bar">
    <select name="my_name">
        <option value="5min">5-Min</option>
        <option value="1hour">Hour</option>
        <option value="1day">Day</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="my_input_submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

#my_bar {
    height: 45px;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#my_bar > select {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#my_bar > input {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Works like a treat.  (Assuming you have a decent browser). Careful with those asterisks though! :)

Comment: In a production site, an appropriate version of `reset.css` should be used.  Here, a mini-reset should suffice.

Answer (score -2):

Flexbox works for sure. If you want to stick to a basic float style layout, you can make some minor adjustments to the `display` and `height` properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/philsinatra/rotppuep/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="my-bar">
    <div class="my-input">
        <select name="my_name" id="my_name">
            <option value="">5 Min</option>
            <option value="">Hour</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-controls">
        <input type="submit" id="my-submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-bar {
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;    
}
.my-input {
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
}
.my-input select {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
}
.form-controls {
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
}
.form-controls input {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
}
```